# OpenMP shared variable seems to be private

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I don't understand why in this code only the thread 0 has n = 1 while the other ones have n = 0 with **shared n**:

```
int main()
{
    int n, tid;

    #pragma omp parallel shared(n) private(tid)
    {
            tid = omp_get_thread_num();
            n = 0;

            if (tid == 0)
            {
                    n++;
            }

            printf("I'am %d, this is my n: %d\n", tid, n);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Output:

```
I'am 5, this is my n: 0
I'am 7, this is my n: 0
I'am 0, this is my n: 1
I'am 2, this is my n: 0
I'am 4, this is my n: 0
I'am 3, this is my n: 0
I'am 6, this is my n: 0
I'am 1, this is my n: 0
```

I'am new with the OMP library. I'am working through ssh on a cluster with 8 nodes, can be this the problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are practically resetting `n` to zero by each thread. Only the thread with `tid==0` will increment `n` prior to printing. Even here, you may encounter the program to print

> I'am 0, this is my n: 0

instead of the expected

> I'am 0, this is my n: 1

since you produced a so-called [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).

If you intend initialize `n` with zero only at the beginning of runtime, you will need to initialize `n` earlier, e.g. prior to starting the parallel section:

```
n = 0;

#pragma omp parallel shared(n) private(tid)
{
        tid = omp_get_thread_num();

        if (tid == 0)
        {
                n++;
        }

        printf("I'am %d, this is my n: %d\n", tid, n);
}
```

Note, however, that the state of `n` in the printed list will then be somewhat random again, since you can never be sure when thread 0 increments the value of `n` to equal 1.

Comment: @Maghio: No worries, race conditions are one of the most often issue in parallel-programming and can be really hard to track down at times. Glad I could help. Please accept my/an answer to indicate that a solution has been found.

Comment: I will use a '#pragma omp barrier' before print!

Comment: @Maghio: Note that you will also need to relocate the initialization of `n` as indicated. Otherwise another thread may reset the value to zero even when using a barrier.

Comment: Is TID assigned according to the order in wich threads call omp_get_thread_num() ?

Comment: @fuesike: That's impossible. During the execution of `omp_set_num_threads()` you don't even *have* any threads yet (because it's outside the `parallel` block), so how would you possibly assign anything to it?

Comment: @Maghio: How the numbers are assigned isn't specified. You just know that the master thread will have 0 and the others any number between 1 and the number of threads minus 1. Even if you knew, how a certain OpenMP implementation assigns the numbers, you shouldn't rely on it because another implementation can do it differently.

Answer (score 0):

Finally this should be the code to get every thread prints "n=1":

```
int main()
{
    int n=0, t;

    #pragma omp parallel shared(n) private(t)
    {
            t = omp_get_thread_num();

            if (t == 0)
            {
                    n++;
            }

            #pragma omp barrier
            printf("Sono %d e ho n = %d\n", t, n);
    }

    return 0;
```

}

Thanks to fuesika.

Comment: And if thread 2 is first to get to "if (t==0)", what then? This small code is prime example on thread race and how things may go wrong. In above example no one can guaranty that thread-0 is to be first executed, due NUMA and other unexpected conditions in (one or more) CORE-s. PS: this answer should be protected as WRONG answer.